# Align sign with numerator

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I have an equation for which I would like the sign to be aligned with the numerator without being a part of it. As a rough example,

```
\[ - \frac{\sqrt{3q\times r^2}}{y \times z} \]
```

produces

[image: fraction with minus sign aligned with middle of fraction]

but I would prefer

[image: fraction with minus sign aligned with numerator]

---

<sub>Rationale: While, in the example above, the default layout is actually better, in my actual document the relevant fraction is coming after a new line and the minus sign is easy to miss. Moving it up to the level of the numerator would make it more conspicuous.</sub>

Comment: `\frac{-\sqrt{3q\times r^2}}{y \times z}` is more mathematically true.

Comment: @JouleV Absolutely! Unfortunately, my example above is meant to be indicative of my problem without containing too much unecessary clutter, and (while a good representation of the question I'm asking) is maybe not a good representation of my actual maths.

Comment: @JouleV more mathematically true?  What does that mean?

Comment: @JPi I meant that it is true and the OP's is false. But as the OP wants to have the wrong one, I said "more mathematically true".

Comment: @JouleV I agree with you in the example I gave. For what it’s worth, my imagined use case was (very roughly) a/b - x/y. In that case, I’d imagine that a/b -x/y (with the sign as part of the numerator) might risk looking like a/b times -x/y. I don’t know whether, in that case, you would agree?

Comment: If you mean a/b times -x/y, you must (or should?) have a bracket! a/b - x/y with the `-` in the very middle is always right.

Comment: @JouleV I don’t. I was just giving the example that it could, in that case, look like someone meant that (but had forgotten the bracket). My priorities for writing equations are, in order: truthfulness, lack of ambiguity, and aesthetics. Unfortunately, the same can’t be said of my question asking, as I should have given a less ambiguous example!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree with your rationale.

Anyway, the customer's always right. `;-)`

Load `mathtools` and do

```
\hphantom{-}\frac{\mathmakebox[0pt][r]{-}\sqrt{3q\times r^2}}{y\times z}
```

[image]

There is a shorthand for `\mathmakebox[0pt][r]{...}`, namely `\mathllap{...}`.

Comment: thanks for help me to know about the tag \mathmakebox...

Comment: Following JouleV's comment ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475470/align-sign-with-numerator/475476#comment1200044_475470 ), I also began to disagree with my own rationale (in the particular case in which I was asking the question). But I figured that the question was worth letting stand for future benefit ;-) Thanks for the solution.

Comment: simpler code: `\mathllap{-}` instead of `\mathmakebox`

Comment: @barbarabeeton the only thing I'm replacing in egregs code is `\mathmakebox[0pt]{r}{-}` the rest is the same including the hphantom.